# Printing Values of dictionary using loop

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I trying to print values of dictionary in serial order, like One Two Three but using below code is displaying random value from dictionary. How can i rectify it! Thank you !!

```
var someDict:[Int:String] = [1:"One", 2:"Two", 3:"Three"]
for keys in someDict.keys
{
//print (keys)
  print(someDict[keys]!)
}
```

Output:

```
Two
Three
One
```

And when i print keys. it shows 2 3 1 :(

Comment: dictionaries are unordered.  If you want a specific order then you need to extract the keys into an array, sort the array and then iterate over the sorted array to access each dictionary element

Comment: okay !! can you show me an example. i am in new in swift.

Comment: Better yet, if your keys are integers, and you want the collection in a specific order, use an array, not a dictionary. Dictionaries are inherently unordered and arrays are inherently ordered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keys of the dictionary is no order.
So you can use other `Array` to save key to ensure order.

Or..

```
for key in someDict.keys.sort ({
    $0 < $1
}) {
    print(someDict[key])
}
```

Chose height performance way according to your demand.

Comment: `someDict.keys.sort()` works too, since Int values conform to the `Comparable` protocol.

Comment: yeah, if need less-than sequence.

Comment: Thank you maquannene and Duncan C, it works perfectly !!